# svn version control authentication fails when run from emacs

Tags: windows, svn, emacs, cygwin, basic-authentication

I'm using on my desktop [native windows emacs 24.2 configured to use cygwin bash](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el).

When I run SVN from cygwin bash everything works fine. It remembers my authorization credentials and connects to a repository. But when I try to run any version-control command from within emacs I always get the following  message:

> svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'https://address.to.repo' svn: E170001: OPTIONS of
>   'https://address.to.repo': authorization failed: Could not
>   authenticate to server: **rejected Basic challenge**

I tried also connect with PSVN interface which also ends up with the same error message. It is somehow strange that it does not work the same way from cygwin terminal and emacs. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you specify **--password** and **--username** explicitly? It also makes sense to clear auth cache: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache

Comment: I cleared auth cache. Ecplictly specified password and user worked from cygwin tty but no improvement from within emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved now. The problem was that Emacs NT cygwin integrated was still using windows HOME path instead of using cygwinized HOME directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the full answer should be something like this:

1. SVN depends on the HOME path to find its per user settings (as most unix programs).
2. In cygwin that varible has something like "/home/pablo".
3. "/home/pablo" is really translated "drive:\cygwin_dir\home\pablo"
4. Emacs-nt grabs its HOME from the windows environment so it is a different HOME than cygwin's
5. emac's vc-svn uses the wrong path to look for its settings.

So there are two solutions (maybe more):

1. Make emacs-nt use the cygwin's HOME (so thats what cygwinization means!! :O), you need setup-cygwin for this, but specially you need one script it depends on cygwin-mount. So emacs-nt can understand cygwin's path "style".
2. (not recomended) The other way around, which is what I did, make cygwin use the window's HOME through a soft cygwin link. `ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/pablo/Roaming/ /home/pablo`
3. Make a soft link so the cygwin's subversion dir points to the windows one `ln -s /cygdrive/c/users/pablo/AppData/Roaming/.subversion /home/pablo/.subversion`

The second solution WILL lead to cygwin's ".bashrc" not executed. So environment variables and aliases defined there won't be define. I still think that it can be done, but I don't have the proper cygwin knowledge needed to tweak that solution. So right now I'm using the solution number 3.